# Removing an already existing element from a list and keeping only one element of that value in the list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list and if there is 2 elements with the same values i want to keep only one

```
l = [1,2,3,2,2]
```

and I want the output to be:

```
[1,2,3]
```

how do i do that ?

Comment: `l = list(set(l))` Set is structure that allows only unique elements.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python remove list duplicates", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the order of elements you can go for this approach

```
result = []
l =  [1,2,3,2,2]
for e in l:
    if e not in result:
        result.append(e)
print(result)
# Result: [1, 2, 3]
```

If the order is not important you can do it in one line as mentioned before

```
list(set(l))
```

Another one-line solution that will keep the order of elements is (Note dictionary hold order of elements in python 3.6+)

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/8692977

```
list({s:None for s in l}.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set()` and `list()`:

```
list(set([1,2,3,2,2]))
# Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

- `set()` removes all duplicates, while not necessarily preserving order.
- `list()` converts the set `{1, 2, 3}` back to a list

As dictionaries are ordered in later versions of Python, this:

```
list(dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,2,2]).keys())
# Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

will preserve order on Python 3.7+, unlike `set()`.

Note:

```
dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,2,2])
# Output: {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

- We generate a (order sensitive) dictionary, using the list items as keys.
- Dictionary keys, like sets, are hashed and so unique - all repetition in the list is discarded
- We then take the keys from the new dictionary and convert back to a list

Comment: Note that using a `set` discards the order of the elements from the original list.

Comment: @nosklo true, offered another solution for Python 3.7+ via dict()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the items from the original list in the same order, use the `unique_everseen` recipe from [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
```

Usage:

```
print(list(unique_everseen(l)))
```